# Why doesn't supportRequestWindowFeature() work?

Tags: android, titlebar

I have a problem and I've been trying to find the mistake for a couple hours but I just can't find it?

My situation:
I don't want that my titlebar appears. My device is a HTC and runs android 2.3.3. I tried it with supportRequestWindowFeature() but somehow it doesn't work.

My code is here:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
```

Also my MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity.

Comment: Do you mean you have both ActionBar and title bar visible?

Comment: Ah I got it I thought it was the title bar but it was actually the actionbar thanks for your help! Stupid mistake from me.

Answer (score 1):

Place `supportRequestWindowFeature` above `super.oncreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```